# vscode maven spring boot no main manifest attribute, in war

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

hello i'm encountering an error while i build a war file through aws ec2....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIEHy.png)
originally it is first time using vscode to spring boot for compile and deploy.
i tried to use a command >> mvn compile war:war / on vscode spring-boot, maven cmd.
as it build through the aws ec2 suddenly this error came out...
**no main manifest attribute, in myclass-m-admin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war spring boot**
i think there is a bunch of solution on .jar whereas, information regarding .war file isn't exsist..please help

```
<!--pom.xml-->
<groupId>com.my.myclass</groupId>
<artifactId>myclass-m-admin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>  
<name>MYCLASS-Admin</name>
<description>M-Admin for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
                        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>main.Main</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Remove the jar plugin.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for reply but it still doesn't work...

Comment: You should execute `mvn package` instead of `war:war`. Also you should not need the goal in the Spring Boot plugin (looks like you are trying to outsmart things in the framework). If that still doesn't work, please add the full `pom.xml` instead of a snippet.